# Is there a difference between a primary drive or a logical one when it's just for storage

Tags: storage

Should I make an external storage drive logical or leave it as primary or does it matter? Also, if I leave it as primary, should I make it active?

Comment: ok so I'm pretty sure you are talking about partitions ON the disk, not the disk itself. On a modern computer I recommend creating GPT partitions rather than MBR partitions, and GPT partitions are neither Primary or Extended/Logical (or you can think of them as only Primary). in MBR, you must have at least 1 primary partition, so unless you want multiple partitions on the disk, just make it primary. Extended/Logical partitions are really just there to get around ancient limitations on the max number of primary partitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I make an external storage drive logical or leave it as primary or does it matter?

If this is a disk with only one partition, just leave that partition as "primary", although it won't really have any effect either way.

For MBR-partitioned disks, this choice only matters if you want more than 4 partitions on the disk. (The MBR partition table format has only four partition slots – each "primary" partition takes up a slot, while all "logical" partitions are crammed into a single slot.) See [this diagram](https://www.easeus.com/images/en/screenshot/partition-manager/logical-vs-primary-3.png).

Meanwhile, GPT-partitioned disks don't have "logical" partitions at all (as the GPT-format partition table has plenty of partition slots anyway).

> Also, if I leave it as primary, should I make it active?

The 'Active' flag is only used at the beginning of the OS boot process (and *only* in the BIOS aka "legacy mode" boot process – not with UEFI). If you aren't booting an OS from the disk in question, then the 'Active' flag doesn't matter at all.